# OpenGL Black rectangle in rendering texture

Tags: opengl, rendertexture

I create textures (for example, I just fill the texture color), and render their. But, for some reason, to the upper edge added black rectangle.

Screenshot:

[image]

```
var
Textures: array of GLuint; 

procedure LoadTexture(const TextureID: Byte; var Texture: GLuint);
var
//
w, h: Cardinal;
//
Data: PByteArray;
begin
//
if TextureID = 0 then
//
  begin
//
w:=512; h:=512;
  end
                 else
//
  begin
//
w:=128; h:=64;
  end;

//
GetMem(Data, w * h * 3);

//
if TextureID = 0 then
//
FillChar(Data^, w * h * 3, 204)
                 else
//
FillChar(Data^, w * h * 3, 102);

//
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);

//
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
//
GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

//
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
//
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

//
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8,
//
w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Data);

//
FreeMem(Data, w * h * 3);
//
Data:=nil;
end;

procedure glInit;
begin
//
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//
SetLength(Textures, 2);
//
glGenTextures(1, @Textures[0]);
//
LoadTexture(0, Textures[0]);
//
glGenTextures(1, @Textures[1]);
//
LoadTexture(1, Textures[1]);

//
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
//
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
//
glClearDepth(1);
//
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

//
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
//
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
//
glLoadIdentity;
//
glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 1);
//
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
//
glLoadIdentity;
end;

procedure glDraw;
begin
//
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
//
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or
  GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[0]);
//
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
//
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
//
glVertex2f(0,   0);
//
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
//
glVertex2f(512, 0);
//
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
//
glVertex2f(512, 512);
//
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
//
glVertex2f(0,   512);
//
glEnd;

//
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[1]);
//
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
//
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
//
glVertex2f(128,   64);
//
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
//
glVertex2f(256, 64);
//
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
//
glVertex2f(256, 128);
//
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
//
glVertex2f(128, 128);
//
glEnd;
end;
```

Comment: Which language it is ? (I haven't seen "var" in c++ or c)

Comment: Object Pascal. Language